# Can angular service worker be considered as service worker to handle the JWT tokens

Tags: angular, jwt, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront, pkce

Problem statement :

We have an application which exposes the JWT token saved in the local storage in the browser[spartacus] and this  JWT token is used for all API call between backend and spartacus.

Current flow :
[image]

First of all the token CANNOT be seen in the browser and the user who login  only able to see the token in the browser.
The concern from the business is that the JWT token is exposed in the browser  and what if someone able to get hold of that token and make the APIs calls via some client or other means, basically if someone hacks .

So business is advising us to follow the below method.

We are planning to implement this https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.4.2

If we introduce a service worker, how would spartacus even make a call to Service worker ?

Will it use some sort of credential to call service worker? if its does isn't the case the credentials will be still exposed in the browser ?

The service worker given in this page https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config#service-worker-configuration will help us to overcome ?

Please advise how can we implement a solution based on the pattern given above, having spartacus as front end and hybris as back end.Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What make you think service worker will help hiding the token? Anything in browsers will be seen. It's just not possible to hide things on user's browsers

Comment: Yes @Jimmy that's correct, if you read the recommended documentation it says "Service workers are run in a separate context from the DOM, have no
   access to the DOM, and the DOM has no access to the service worker.
   This makes service workers the most secure place to store tokens, as
   an XSS attack is unable to exfiltrate the tokens." so assume in this case service worker would be a micro service center in hosted seperately. How does it gonna help. But still can angular js can handle such use case of acting as a service worker?

Comment: hmm, no, I read that. But what I mean is your main reason for using SW is to hide the token - this isn't gonna work so instead of using some kind of trendy SW, you could just stick to old options to localStorage or cookies.

Comment: Thanks @Jimmy appreciate that but business doesn't seem to understand that the way we implemented is a standard way. Appreciate your time andcresponsw